# Enums with special characters : How to?

Tags: java, enums, special-characters, java-6

I currently work on a parser. I walk a tree, most of it being quite determinist (I have a finite number of values I can find).

Usually in these cases, I create an enum with the name of the value I expect to find, like this :

```
public enum myElements{
    like, 
    not_like,// "not like" is transformed in not_like by parser
    exists;
}
```

in this case, I can check whether a string belongs to the enum this way :

```
String my_string;
myElements.valueOf(my_string);
```

The thing is that currently I work with special characters ({">", "<", "<>", ...)
It is not possible to create enum value with special characters.

What I would like is to associate an enum with those special characters elements, something like

```
public enum myElements{
    greather_than(">"), 
    smaller_than("<")
}
```

and continue using something as straightforward as:

```
myElements.valueOf(my_string);
```

For the moments I use enums everywhere but for these elements, where I use of table. I'd like to harmonize this

BTW, I work with Java6, due to some dependancies.

An idea is welcome, 
Thanks !

**EDIT :**

Here is an example of the current table version I use :

```
public static String[] compElements = {">", "<", "<>", "=", "<=", ">="};
```

with the equivalent for the valueOf :

```
Arrays.asList(compElements).contains(my_string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want your enum to store a map of all the "flexible" names, mapping the name to the enum value. You wouldn't be able to use `valueOf`, but you could easily write your own static method to return the relevant mapped value. Create the map in a static initializer block. (Don't forget that when the constructors are called automatically, static initializers will *not* have executed.)

Sample code:

```
public enum Foo {
  // Idiomatic Java names. You could ignore those if you really want,
  // and overload the constructor to have a parameterless one which calls
  // name() if you really want.
  FIRST("first"),
  SECOND("second"),
  WITH_SPACE("with space");

  private static final Map<String, Foo> nameToValueMap;

  static {
    // Really I'd use an immutable map from Guava...
    nameToValueMap = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
    for (Foo foo : EnumSet.allOf(Foo.class)) {
      nameToValueMap.put(foo.friendlyName, foo);
    }
  }

  private final String friendlyName;

  private Foo(String friendlyName) {
    this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
  }

  public String getFriendlyName() {
    return friendlyName;
  }

  public static Foo fromFriendlyName(String friendlyName) {
    return nameToValueMap.get(friendlyName);
  }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't having an enum + a map more complex than the table I have right now ? Would you give more importance into having only enums + a Map, or keep the table version ?

Comment: @jlengrand: It's impossible to tell, given that you haven't given us any indication of what your "table" approach does. The enum+map version automatically keeps itself in line with reality though...

Comment: Thx for the answer. I put an example of table and the corresponding function in my post. I think I'll go with the enum to keep consistency with the rest of my code.

Comment: Thx ! It works, simply took me some time because valueOF returns an Exception, while fromFriendlyName doesn't .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map to pair your enums with special characters.

```
myElements.valueOf(my_string);
```

could be

```
MyClass.translateToEnum(my_string);
```

which would use your Map object to determine which enum to return.

Comment: Yep, that's basically what I have righ now :). Thx

Comment: That's the way to go.  I've used that pattern before, and I don't think it is too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the toString method of each enum to hold the value you need.  Im not sure if this is what you are after though?